# decode legacy crypt-ed file with mcrypt

Tags: ubuntu, unix, solaris

I have an old file which I encrypted with old UNIX-style `crypt` on Solaris. (Yes, I know it's weak, but it was appropriate in this case.)

I now want to decrypt it but I am running Ubuntu which doesn't have `crypt` but rather `mcrypt` as a "replacement" which, at least in default mode, is something else entirely.

Are there options which will make `mcrypt` behave like `crypt` or do I need to build it from source? In which case, where is the source?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At [this site](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2251496) , someone answered about "Solaris 10u9 (x86_64) and Oracle Linux (RHEL) 5.6":

> On Linux
>
> mcrypt -V -d -a enigma -o scrypt --bare sample.bin

to decrypt sample.bin encrypt in the solaris. You didn't say which solaris version you're using, so I can't tell you if it'll work for you.